# strange leading unicode in html form post

Tags: character-encoding

Occasionally I get these errors occurring:

```
An invalid character was found in the mail header: '‎'
```

which didn't make any sense, upon investigation it seems there's some invisible character in there.

I know which user this is, so I select them from the DB:

```
select email from user where email = 'their@address.com'
```

the user's email appears as `their@address.com`, but copying it into a text editor, shows a wierd leading char:

[image]

So why does the sql equality operator match, when it isnt the same string? because its some invisible char?

<strike>If I save just that leading char in the text file as unicode and open it in a hex editor, I see this:</strike>

```
FF FE 0E 20
```

**Update:** the offending bytes are:

```
E2 80 8E
```

What is this crazyness, how did it get there?

How can I prevent this in future, and how can I clean my database (as there are a few of these)

These are the relevant headers from when the user was created:

```
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Accept: application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01
Accept-Charset: ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.3
Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate,sdch
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The bytes FF FE are U+FEFF BYTE ORDER MARK in UTF-16BE encoding, and 0E 20 are U+200E LEFT-TO-RIGHT MARK in the same encoding. At the start of a file, they are harmless, at least if the content is in a left-to-right writing system, like the Latin alphabet.

I cannot make a guess on their origin, especially since I didn’t quite get what file is being discussed and how it was created (from a form post? from the database? some other way? how?).

Comment: i was saving the offending characters to file so i could simply get at the hex for them. thanks for clarifying about the BOM, learned something new :) ive updated the question

Comment: E2 80 8E is the UTF-8 encoded form of U+0E20. (I checked this out using http://www.ltg.ed.ac.uk/~richard/utf-8.html )

Comment: Sorry for my initial confusion; I have edited my answer accordingly. E2 80 8E is UTF-8 for U+0E20, but the data most probably isn’t meant to contain it but U+200E, which has the bytes in the opposite order in UTF-16. So what you have has originated from UTF-16BE data that has been misinterpreted as UTF-16LE data and then converted to UTF-8. So even the byte order mark itself has been misinterpreted in the wrong endianness.

Comment: I've looked at the logs for the whole `POST` and the email field is the only one with a leading `U+200E`, so my guess is they copy and pasted their email address in to the field from a badly encoded email.

Comment: How can I strip such characters? I'm already validating the email address, and it passed, presumably this special char is tricking my code?

Comment: i'm going to assume the user copied their address from a badly encoded email or something.

Answer (score 1):

FFFE is a [Unicode Byte Order Mark (BOM)](http://www.unicode.org/faq/utf_bom.html).

**Edit:**

0E20 is [THAI CHARACTER PHO SAMPHAO](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/0e20/index.htm). No idea where that could come from.

Comment: oh i see, so thats just the start of the text file, and not relevant here. its the `0E20` thats important?

Comment: updated the question with the offending bytes, messed it up originally